# Spring boot with H2 Database auto create

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I am using embeded H2 in my java application via spring boot. Currently, it **creates(overrides)** my tables in the DB. But once I push it to production
I do not want my tables to be wiped off and recreated, so I wont lose the previous datas in the tables. But I am not sure how to accomplish this. Not sure what to put on the line  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`. I tried validate and other options but did not work out. Here is my application.properties. Thanks

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical- 
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Answer (score 11):

You should use update here:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This will build the tables on startup if they're not already defined, otherwise it will leave them as they are.

Also when you do that, you might want to drop the line:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Finally, the best way to do this is to have different sets of properties for different environments, either by passing them in as run time variables or ideally externalising them with something like spring config server.

Comment: I'm sorry but why are you voting this down? I have done this hundreds of times and I know it works.

Comment: Because it's plain wrong: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl

Comment: No; it's not. I think you should endeavour to understand what you're talking about before lackadaisically go around voting down people's answers. Go and try update for yourself and see what it does.

Comment: Look, the official documentation of Hibernate says that the update option is for "Update the database schema". The answer from Daisy Day says it "leaves the tables as they are". Those are clearly not compatible together, so one of them is wrong. Which of them has the biggest probability of being right. Considering that the name of the option is "Update", and not "LeaveAsTheyAre"? FYI, I have answered 2239 questions about Hibernate here, and gained 70K+ rep points by doing so (not counting JPA questions). So maybe, maybe, I know a little bit about what I'm talking about.

Comment: The question was specifically about avoiding having schema destroyed and data wiped. Using update will achieve this, assuming he's not going to change the model before starting up the application against the same database. I also said ideally you'd have different configuration for different environments, which is very valid. It's not 'plain wrong'. It's a valid answer for what he was asking and would work and doesn't just deserve voting down. Apologies for the terminology 'leave as they are' - in his use case that is true.

Comment: P.S. I doubt the intention of reputation points is so that people can laud them over one another when there's a disagreement but stay classy.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion maybe it is my bad. Basically, I want my spring boot to create my schema automatically and add some data into tables with looking into my import.sql. If the tables exists then do not recreate the schema nor run the import sql. I tried spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update with spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true and with spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false. But this does not work for me. It does not run my import.sql so my tables will have some data in them. Also, if it set to update if the tables are not there it does not even create tables. Hopefully this will clarify the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto explicitly and the standard Hibernate property values are **none, validate, update, create, and create-drop**

Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks your database is embedded. It defaults to create-drop if no schema manager has been detected or none in all other cases. An embedded database is detected by looking at the Connection type. hsqldb, h2, and derby are embedded, and others are not. Be careful when switching from in-memory to a ‘real’ database that you do not make assumptions about the existence of the tables and data in the new platform. You either have to set ddl-auto explicitly or use one of the other mechanisms to initialize the database

Following cases might applicable for you:

**update:**

The update operation for example will attempt to add new columns, constraints, etc but will never remove a column or constraint that may have existed previously but no longer does as part of the object model from a prior run.

**none:**

In production, it's often highly recommended you use none or simply don't specify this property. That is because it's common practice for DBAs to review migration scripts for database changes, particularly if your database is shared across multiple services and applications.

In addition, a file named **import.sql** in the root of the classpath is executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that is, if the ddl-auto property is set to create or create-drop). This can be useful for demos and for testing if you are careful but is probably not something you want to be on the classpath in production. It is a Hibernate feature (and has nothing to do with Spring).

Comment: But my problem is  I have an data.sql file that spring uses to insert rows into my tables. If it set it "update" once the application is launched next time the spring will try to run data.sql again but wont be able to because of trying to those rows already exists and cant add the same values with the primay keys. What I want to do is, where first time when the user launches the application it will create the schema/tables and add rows into tables I have in data.sql and next time when the application is launched. It wont override or add these. I want to keep my data persistent in the tables

Comment: I have edited my ans and in your case you need to remove it from classpath on production.

Answer (score 3):

For .yaml, you can do that

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:path
    username: sa
    password: 
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
  h2:
    console.enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing below line.

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish your dev code from productions, use Spring profiles. Then you can define whatever behavior you want for each environment.

It is also OK to define the general (production) behavior in `application.properties`, and override them (for `local` profile) `application-local.properties`. Spring has a sophisticated fallback mechanism for this.