# Weird behaviour creating table in schema.sql vs via H2-console?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I am trying to execute the following SQL via schema.sql as my Spring Boot application starts:

```sql
    create table tbl_user(
    id int auto_increment, name varchar2(50), primary key(id)
    );
```

When I try to run an insert statement against this with H2-console I get:

```
    NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
    insert into tbl_user(name) values ('Bob') [23502-200] 23502/23502
```

However, if I drop the table and run the same creation and insertion using H2-console the insert succeeds without an error.

```
    2021-01-30 20:17:24.325  INFO 38184 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : 
    HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
    2021-01-30 20:17:24.380  INFO 38184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : 
    HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
    2021-01-30 20:17:24.543  INFO 38184 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : 
    HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    2021-01-30 20:17:24.646  INFO 38184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : 
    HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    2021-01-30 20:17:25.129  INFO 38184 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : 
    HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: 
    [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=h2user
    spring.datasource.password=h2password
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Comment: Which generation stretegy do you use in @Entity class ID field?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you adding spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none to avoid H2 database auto-creation done by spring boot.

You can read the post at [Spring boot with H2 Database auto create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691744/spring-boot-with-h2-database-auto-create) and the spring boot documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-database-initialization.