# In Spring Starter Project, Values are not fetching into h2 database

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm new to Spring Framework. While Creating Spring Starter Project, I've selected Web,JPA & H2 database then I've created Alien.Class with 2 Variables and i've created data.sql file, by using this file i've tried to fetch the values into h2 database. But after adding data.sql file, i got an error that shows Failed to execute SQL script statement nested exception is Table "ALIEN" not found; SQL statement: insert into alien values (101, 'Vikram').Please, give a solution for this.

1.Alien.Class

```
package com.telusko.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Alien 
{
    @Id
    private int aid;
    private String aname;
    public int getAid() {
        return aid;
    }
    public void setAid(int aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }
    public String getAname() {
        return aname;
    }
    public void setAname(String aname) {
        this.aname = aname;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alien [aid=" + aid + ", aname=" + aname + "]";
    }
}
```

2.home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

        <form action="addAlien">
            <input type="text" name="aid"><br>
            <input type="text" name="aname"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

3.AlienController

```
ackage com.telusko.demo.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AlienController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home.jsp";
    }
}
```

4.application.properties

```
server.port=8082
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:navin
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

5.data.sql

```
insert into alien values (101,'Navin');
```

6.Console error

```
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:51.919[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.telusko.demo.BootjpaApplication     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting BootjpaApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-JF5BSMC with PID 2788 (C:\Users\Lakshmana Sai\SpringWorkspace\bootjpa\target\classes started by Lakshmana Sai in C:\Users\Lakshmana Sai\SpringWorkspace\bootjpa)
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:51.923[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.telusko.demo.BootjpaApplication     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The following profiles are active: @spring.profiles.active@
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:52.856[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:52.876[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:53.672[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:53.690[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:53.691[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.111[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.124[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.124[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2125 ms
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.166[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.462[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.476[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:navin'
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.680[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration$SharedCredentialsDataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Lakshmana%20Sai/SpringWorkspace/bootjpa/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into alien values (101,'Navin'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALIEN" not found; SQL statement:
insert into alien values (101,'Navin') [42102-200]
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.682[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.693[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.705[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.745[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2021-05-31 07:17:54.844[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m2788[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration$SharedCredentialsDataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Lakshmana%20Sai/SpringWorkspace/bootjpa/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into alien values (101,'Navin'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALIEN" not found; SQL statement:
insert into alien values (101,'Navin') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.telusko.demo.BootjpaApplication.main(BootjpaApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Lakshmana%20Sai/SpringWorkspace/bootjpa/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into alien values (101,'Navin'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALIEN" not found; SQL statement:
insert into alien values (101,'Navin') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:72) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializationConfiguration$InitializationModeDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.java:204) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:131) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:91) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyDataScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALIEN" not found; SQL statement:
insert into alien values (101,'Navin') [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7599) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1747) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691744/spring-boot-with-h2-database-auto-create

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using ?

Comment: This is the solution for my problem ---> By default, data.sql scripts are now run before Hibernate is initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based initialization with that of Flyway and Liquibase. If you want to use data.sql to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true. While mixing database initialization technologies is not recommended, this will also allow you to use a schema.sql script to build upon a Hibernate-created schema before it’s populated via data.sql.

Answer (score 0):

H2 is trying to make table names to uppercase and doing case sensitive search so it is unable to find the table.

Try to use `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE` property and see if it works.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:navin;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE
```

Comment: I've done as you said but got the same Console error